# Loop List and change a property - Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to calculate the amount of achievements in runtime and set it into the application object inside the page but the totalAchivements goes outside the object.

Basically the `totalAchievements` should be inside of each application.

[image: y o]

Controller

```
    Page<UserApplication> userApplications = userApplicationRepository.findByUserUsername(pageable, username);
for(UserApplication userApplication : userApplications.getContent()) {

    long totalAchievements = achievementRepository.countByApplicationApplicationId(userApplication.getApplication().getApplicationId());

    userApplication.setTotalAchievements(totalAchievements);
}
 return new ResponseEntity<>(userApplications, HttpStatus.OK);
```

Model

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_APPLICATION")
public class UserApplication {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId", referencedColumnName="userId")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"}) 
    @JsonIgnore
    private User user;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "applicationId", referencedColumnName="applicationId")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"}) 
    private Application application;
    @Transient
    private long totalAchievements;

}
```

Comment: IMO you are misreading the console log and the `totalAchievements` is where you want them?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the totalAchievements to be inside the application object, then you have to add the member inside the Application entity.

```
@Entity
class Application{
    @Transient
    private long totalAchievements;
}
```

Then set it as

```
userApplication.getApplication().setTotalAchievements(totalAchievements);
```